# Show that $P(A\cap B) \geq 1-P(A^{c})-P(B^{c})$.

Tags: probability, proof-writing

So far I have:

$$P(A\cap B)  = 1-P((A\cap B)^{c})    $$   (complement axiom)
                                 $$= \[1-P(A^{c}\cup B^{c})\]$$  (DeMorgan's)
                                       =...
I'm not sure what to do after this ;(

Comment: **Hint:** Inclusion-exclusion rearranged a bit tells us that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

Comment: As a mathjax suggestion, I applaud you for trying to typeset it.  It is more common to use `\cup` and `\cap` than `\bigcup` and `\bigcap` for the intersection of just two sets.  You normally see `\bigcup` and `\bigcap` for iterated union/intersection as in $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k$ similarly to how $\sum$ is used.  [More mathjax tips here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note that the statement you have to prove is equivalent to $$P(A)-P(B^c)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)-1=P(A\cup B)-1\leq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any event $C$, $P[C]\le 1$. So $P[A\cup B]\le 1\iff -P[A\cup B]\ge -1$. Call this inequality $(a)$. Note that $P[A\cup B]=P[A]+P[B]-P[A\cap B]\implies P[A\cap B]=P[A]+P[B]-P[A\cup B]$. Using $(a)$ in here, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $1-P(A^c)-P(B^c) = P(A) + P(B) - 1$

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the inequality in the following way

$$ P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B) - 1 $$

And thus

$$ 1 \geq P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) $$

which implies

$$ 1 \geq P(A \cup B) $$

which is true always